# Как исправить ошибку получения документа Firebase

Tags: java, android, строки, файлы, firebase

Есть приложение для андроид и firebase.
Отлично авторизуется(регистрация и вход)
Но при успешном входе вылазит ошибка :

```
errorFailed to get document because client is offline
```

а также при откладке

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.savenko.cyberblog.app, PID: 10922
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error in Firestore (0.6.6-dev).
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeux.run(Unknown Source:21)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
     Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Can't serialize <ServerTimestamp localTime=Timestamp(seconds=1586459308, nanos=427000000)>
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeut.zzl(Unknown Source:6)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzetr.zzd(Unknown Source:358)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzetr.zzc(Unknown Source:31)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzetr.zzl(Unknown Source:440)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeox.zza(Unknown Source:87)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeqs.zzb(Unknown Source:22)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeoz.zza(Unknown Source:23)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzepg.run(Unknown Source:6)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeqn.zzb(Unknown Source:18)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeoz.zzd(Unknown Source:28)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeoa.zza(Unknown Source:25)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzenb.zza(Unknown Source:58)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzenf.zze(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeni.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeuu$zza.run(Unknown Source:16)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: Возможно нужен код?)

Comment: Нужен код, можно посмотреть порядок действия через лог, можно отловить через try catch итд